# How to remove last two screen

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, flutter-getx

I have some screen - `(A-B-C-D-E-F)` and from `F` screen I want to remove `D-E-F` screen and land to `C` Screen. So screen in stack : (A-B-C).
Can you let me know how can I do this.
I already try:

```
 Get.offUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()),(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

and

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                          Second()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                    }),
```

But not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stack of pages A-B-C-D-E and want to push F onto the stack using get x it would look like this

```
Get.to(F())
```

or

```
Get.toName('/F')
```

Outside of that using named routes makes things easier
If you have a stack of pages A-B-C-D-E and want to push F onto the stack but pop D and E then it would look like this

```
Get.offNamedUntil('/F', ModalRoute.withName('/C')
```

This gives you a stack of A-B-C-F

If you have a stack of A-B-C-D-E-F and want to pop until C then it would look like this

```
Get.until((route) => Get.currentRoute == '/C')
```

This would give you a stack of A-B-C popping off D-E-F in one line of code

[Here is a video showing the above code working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqSx.jpg)

Comment: Please share those solution which actually work or you try at your end.

Comment: This most definitely does work but I'll update my answer to better inform you

Answer (score 0):

try this

Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/c'));

or you can simply pop 3 times like

Navigator.of(context)..pop()..pop()..pop();

Comment: Can you explain how can i achieve this using GetX. and I don't want to use back(), back().

Answer (score 0):

### Do this on your third route

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(   context,   MaterialPageRoute(settings: RouteSettings(name: "Foo")), );
```

**and at last screen you can call this.**

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("Foo"));
```

Comment: Can you explain how can i achieve this using GetX.

Answer (score 0):

For skip two screen like - `A-B-C-D-F` screen in my stack and I want to go to `B` by removing all upper screen in stack then final stack is `A-B.`

**In Screen B**

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    settings: RouteSettings(name: "Foo"),
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Third()),
              );
```

**And In Screen F**

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("Foo"));
```

It working perfectly fine But is there any option we can achieve this in GetX.

Answer (score 0):

When we move form one to another screen then use:

```
Get.toNamed(RoutersConst.third);
```

And to remove screen from stack then use

```
Get.until((route) => route.settings.name == RoutersConst.second);
```